# Can I install Ubuntu 13.04 on ibm thinkpad a31

Tags: 13.04, system-installation

I have an IBM Thinkpad and want to install Ubuntu. These are my specs:

- 512mb ram
- ATI mobility radeon 7000 graphics card

I don't know the rest

Is it possible to install Ubuntu 13.04 on it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! New questions about [end-of-life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29) Ubuntu releases are considered off-topic as per the [help/on-topic]. These old releases are unsupported and their use is not recommended. They don't even get updates for newly discovered security vulnerabilities, which makes using them risky. If you install or upgrade to [a supported release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Stable) and this question still applies, please flag and/or comment to request it be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Make sure you get the latest version of Ubuntu (13.10) or the Long Term Support version (12.04) of Ubuntu. If your laptop cannot run Ubuntu, you could try  [Debain](http://www.debian.org) or similar Linux distribution. You can 'test' if it works by creating a [Live DVD or USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD)

Comment: Ok cool I have done the usb thing before. Will unity desktop environment work?

Comment: Yes, works just like a normal installation except (unless you have persistence on the usb) every time you restart the operating system, all changes will be reverted.